# Passing Dynamic Variables Via Dot Notation Function Call

Tags: javascript

In my Node/MongoDB backend I make a call using dot notation that looks like this:

```
await this.sybase.Clients.add(args.doc, args.metaData, this.app);
```

Now, to make this more usable, I want to be able to input dynamic variables. Specifically, where you see "Clients" I want to use a variable called "model", which I will be able to assign as needed.

I also want to be able to use a dynamic variable where you see "add" -- something like "action".

If this were a string I would just do this:

```
`this.sybase.${model}.${action}(args.doc, args.metaData, this.app)`
```

But clearly that won't work here. So how can I pass dynamic variables in a case like this?

Comment: `this.sybase[model][action](...)`

Comment: you can use variables in object calls like this `this.sybase[model][add]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation:

```js
let someObj = {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3};
let key = "bar";
console.log(someObj[key]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors